# Zeros are appending to my arrays in Java programm

Tags: java, arrays

If I print my `array long pair[]` , zeros are appending in empty slots. What is wrong? Any help is welcome.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        diff = arr[j] - arr[i];
        if (ndiff == diff) {
            pair[x] = arr[i];
            x++;
            pair[x] = arr[j];
            x++;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i!=pair.length;i++){
    System.out.print(pair[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: What did you expect the empty slots to contain? 0 is the default value of numeric primitive types. If you prefer nulls, use Integer[] instead of int[].

Comment: In Java all types have default values, for primitive `long` the default is `0`. What did you expect?

Comment: @Eran worth noting that there is quite a speed penalty for an `Object[]` over a primitive one.

Comment: -20 30 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 when i print the array this is the output i only expected the first two elements.

Comment: @sandy1603 then change the value of n accordingly

Comment: @sandy1603 you have 20 boxes. You put a number of balls in the first two boxes. You then count the number of balls in **every** box - what makes you think that there won't be 0 balls in the remaining 18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print only the values you put in `pair`, your `for` loop should run only up to the element with index `x-1`:

```
for(i=0; i < x; i++){
    System.out.print(pair[i]+" ");
}
```